# get data from json after successful login to facebook

Tags: json, facebook, ionic-framework

I'm implement ionic facebook login in my app and I succeed to login but the issue I don't know how to access to data. i want to get the uid,email,displayName and more.

this is my facebook login

```
loginFacebook() {
    let provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(() => {
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then((userData)=>{
      let profileUs = JSON.stringify(userData);
      console.log('my json:' +userData);
      // i want to get uid,email,displayName

    }).catch(function(error){
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to access `userData`'s attributes:

```
loginFacebook() {
    let provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(() => {
        firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then((userData)=>{
            let uid = userData.user.uid
            let displayName = userData.user.displayName

        }).catch(function(error){
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    })
}
```